# how to can getting datagridview rows data to displaey text boxes in another form?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wrote a program that does work with files like delete and update, store, and search And all customers and Orders and products and Employees.

But I read a row from the grid and then click the "**btnCustomerView**" button display selected row data in another form text box

[**Project File**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwfe0ciishw3dyz/CoustomersApp5.rar?m=)

[**Please See Video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlm8Maxwc1U&feature=youtu.be)

```
   private void customerViewGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = this.customerViewGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        var selectedItme = row.Cells["Id"].Value;
        var objCustomer = customerBusiness.Load(Convert.ToInt32(selectedItme));

    }
```

Thanks.